# How to edit transaction data of an ethereum transaction? Or in other words, create a manual transaction, for contracts with no front end?

Tags: ethereumjs

This strikes me as a very stupid question, but I have googled and cannot find an easy answer. I have identified a contract that I want to interact with- I know the function selector and the variables I want to pass- ie everything that I need to know for the transaction data. But there is no front-end layer on this contract so I can't use metamask or similar.

Wat do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Remix:

- Create the ABI with the skeleton of the contract, for instance in Remix.

Then in NodejJs:

- Get the mnemonic or the private key that you want to use to interact with Ethereum.
- Create a Web3 instance with a [HDWalletProvider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider) to connect to Infura.io.
- Create a [Web3 contract instance](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth-contract.html) with the ABI and the deployed address.
- Interact with this contract instance in Javascript.

Comment: I will check this out as well! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may use "Write Contract" feature of [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/): https://etherscan.io/address/0xdb25f211ab05b1c97d595516f45794528a807ad8#writeContract, but your contract has to have verified source code on [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/) and you need to use [Web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/) enabled browser such as [Metamask](https://metamask.io/).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks!